# Blacklist characters in xml data using xsd pattern

Tags: c#, regex, xml, xsd, pattern-matching

I guess this is a basic questions but the pattern seem quite confusing to me. 
I would like to blacklist some characters like + , -, @, #, <, >. 
If the characters are in an xml field, then I would like to invalidate the xml.

In the below example, I want to return the xml as invalid if the string field contains any of the above mentioned characters. 
If data is something like this "hello". It should be valid. 
How should I write my pattern. Thanks for checking on this.

XML:

```
<DataType>System.String</DataType>
<Value>
      <String>Data@yours</String>
</Value>
```

in XSD:

```
<xs:element name="Value">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="String" type="xs:string" />
</xs:sequence>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="[^+-@#%&()<>?]"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Further editing this part:

I have been getting these errors:
An error occurred while parsing EntityName. - in my code
The entity name must immediately follow the & in the entity reference in the only xsd validator tool. http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.VzTwcYSDFBc

It doesn't seem to follow these special characters, How can I change this?
Thanks again.

Comment: Just a thought, if the regex in there is supposed to match for **valid** strings, shouldn't it be `[^+-@#%&()<>?]+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that acc. to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html):

> Particularly noteworthy is the complete absence of anchors like the caret and dollar, word boundaries, and lookaround. XML schema always implicitly **anchors the entire regular expression**. **The regex must match the whole element for the element to be considered valid.**

So, to match a string that does not contain `+`, `@`, `#`, `%`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>`, `?`, `-` (at least 1 symbol), you need to use

```
<xs:pattern value="[^+@#%&amp;()&lt;&gt;?-]+"/>
```

Note that `<`, `>` and `&` should be entitized to be used inside an XML attribute value.

If you want to allow empty value, `*` should be used instead of `+`. Note that `-` is put at the end of the pattern so as not to create any range like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have been trying to implement the same. But I have been getting this error. - An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Is there anything wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Sorry, I have completely forgotten about that part. Check If you can use `&gt;` and `&lt;` first. And `&` must be `&amp;`.

Comment: Thanks again. However, I am still getting an error on the online tool for xsd validator. http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.VzTwcYSDFBc Element string has both type attribute and anonymous type child. Only one of this is allowed for an element.

Comment: The link is not showing any test XML/XSD. Please paste the whole samples into the question so that I could test.

Comment: Sorry about that. Looks the the problem is fixed now. I have specified the type as string twice here - <xs:element name="String" type="xs:string" /> After removing type, it works fine!